# Как запустить JAR файл Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

Написал телеграм бота используя Spring Boot

В Intellij IDEA все работает , но когда я пытаюсь запустить JAR файл все время выбрасывается

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name .
```

Это уже 3 по счету проблема на которой я окончательно встал. Всю голову изломал, должен быть способ запускать JAR без танцев с бубном,

Прошу помощи.

**Пример**

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.example.demo.UltraGangstaMegaBotApplication.main(UltraGangstaMegaBotApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 19 more

I:\Users\El_Chupa\Desktop\JAVA\JAVA Projects\gradleproject2\UltraGangstaMegaBot\out\artifacts\UltraGangstaMegaBot_jar>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UltraGangstaMegaBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Библиотека для парсинга эмоджи-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: а как вы собирали этот jar? (это важно)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Project Structure - Artifacts -+ - JAR from modules with dependencies - выбор мейн класс. Далее Build - Build Artifact - Action Build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сбор jar файла далеко не всегда такой простой процесс. Особенно если в нем огромное количество зависимостей.

И для приложения разработанного на Spring, описанный Вами способ сборки

> 1. Сначала добавляем артефакт
>
>    1. `Project Structure`
>    2. `Artifacts`
>    3. `JAR from modules with dependencies`
>    4. `выбор мейн класс`
> 2. Далее выполняем сборку
>
>    1. `Build`
>    2. `Build Artifact`
>    3. `Action Build`

**НЕ ПОДОЙДЁТ!**

При таком способе все зависимости просто разархивируются и складываются внутрь нового JAR-файла. При этом если в разных зависимостях в корне будут лежать одноименные файлы настроек - они просто будут перезаписываться друг другом.

**Но не спешите горевать!**.
О Вас уже позаботились.

Собственно подключенный вами плагин `spring-boot-maven-plugin` навешивает на стадию `package` жизненного цикла проекта Maven все необходимые для сборки jar-файла задания .

Все что Вам стоит сделать - это собрать проект с помощью Maven (а не с помощью встроенного функционала идеи)

#### Сборка с помощью пользовательского интерфейса

Сделать это можно на одноименной вкладке Maven (Как правило расположена на панели справа сверху)

`Maven` -> `Lifecycle` -> `package`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Сборка в терминале

Если же Вы собираете на сервере, или просто из консоли, то в корневой папке проекта(там где лежит pom.xml) можно выполнить команду

```
mvn package
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат и там и там будет одинаковым.

Вам нужно будет искать файл `target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо. Все получилось.)

Comment: @Roman, если что-то не будет получаться пишите

Comment: @Roman, если по спрингу не будет никто отвечать - можете меня пингануть (я посмотрю)

Comment: Хорошо , спасибо)